# find that log(a)'s value type if a is null on SQL server 2008 R2.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, exception, windows-7

I need to find that log(null)'s value type on SQL server 2008 R2.

```
DECLARE @factor1 float      
set @factor1 = log(null)
if  @factor1 is null 
    print '@factor1 is '+ cast(@factor1 as varchar(100))
if  isnumeric(@factor1) = 1
    print '@factor1 is num'
```

Why no exception is thrown for log(null) ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a message for a NULL value, you should handle the null value of @factor1.

You can't concatenate a string with NULL , it yields NULL .

```
DECLARE @factor1 float      
set @factor1 = log(null)
if  @factor1 is null 
    print '@factor1 is '+ isnull(cast(@factor1 as varchar(100)),'null')
if  isnumeric(@factor1) = 1
    print '@factor1 is num'
```

Returns:

> @factor1 is null

Comment: Any operation on null is generally null, but you can do `DECLARE @factor1 float; set @factor1 = log(null); select @factor1` to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is not zero.  NULL passed to any scalar function will return NULL. (Exception: UDF code could, of course, detect null and deliberately throw an exception.)

Conceptually, NULL means "I don't know!". The logarithm of "I don't know" is something I don't know. I don't know for a fact that it doesn't exist.

If you *want* an error if the source value is NULL, then try:

```
LOG(COALESCE(NULL,0))
```